# AJAX call works in Chrome and Safari but not in Firefox and IE?

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, firefox, jquery-validate

This is my code to reset a user's password incase the user forgets his password. The data is sent to the PHP code via AJAX requests and the PHP code simply echoes a "Y" or "N" depending upon the validity of the inputs.

The problem is, the AJAX calls does not work in Firefox 19 and IE 9. I haven't tried in other versions of IE. The AJAX calls work perfectly in chrome and safari. Has anyone been through the same problem? Can anyone help please?

```
    <title> Forgot Password? </title>    

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jzaefferer.github.com/jquery-  validation/jquery.validate.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css">

        label.error { color: red;  }

        #status { color: green; }

    </style>

    <script>

        $(document).ready(function(){

            $('#code_form').hide();

            $('#password_form').hide();

            $("#email_form").validate({

                onkeyup: false,

                rules: {

                  email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                  }
                },

                messages: {
                  email: {
                  required: "Please enter your email ID.",
                  email: "Please enter a valid email ID."
                 }
               }

            });


            $('#email_send').click(function() {

                event.preventDefault();

                var email = $('#email').val();

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "reset_code.php",

                    data: {email: email},
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(response){

                    if(response == "Y")
                    {
                        $('#code_form').show();
                        $('#email_send').hide();
                        $('#status').html("Check your mail for the reset code.");

                    }
                    else
                    {

                        $('#status').html("Looks like you have entered a wrong email ID.");

                    }

                 }

            });

            });


            $("#code_form").validate({

                onkeyup: false,

                rules: {

                  code: {
                    required: true,
                    digits: true
                  }
                },

                messages: {
                  code: {
                  required: "Please enter the code received in your mail.",
                  digits: "Please enter the code received in your mail."
                 }
               }

             });

             $('#code_send').click(function() {

               event.preventDefault();

               var email = $('#email').val();
               var code = $('#code').val();


                $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "code_verify.php",

                data: {email: email, code: code},
                cache: false,
                success: function(response){

                    if(response == "Y")
                    {
                        $('#password_form').show();
                        $('#code_send').hide();
                        $('#status').html("Ok, now enter your password twice before you forget again.");

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $('#status').html("Please enter the code received in your mail.");
                    }

                }

            });

            });


            $("#password_form").validate({

                onkeyup: false,

                rules: {

                  password: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 8
                  },
                  repassword: {
                    required: true,
                    equalTo: "#password"  
                  }
                }

            });

            $('#password_send').click(function() {

               event.preventDefault();

               var email = $('#email').val();
               var password = $('#password').val();
               var repassword = $('#repassword').val();

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "update_password.php",

                    data: {email: email, password: password, repassword: repassword},
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(response){

                    if(response == "Y")
                    {

                        $('#email_form').hide();
                        $('#code_form').hide();
                        $('#password_form').hide();
                        $('#status').html("Password reset successful. Proceed to <a href=index.php>login</a> page. ");


                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $('#status').html("Oops. Something went wrong. Try again.");

                    }

                }


            });

        });

    });


    </script>

</head>

<body class="oneColElsCtr">

    <div class ="about_body"> 

        <a href="index.php"><img src="images/title_block_logon.png" style="margin-    top:25px; margin-bottom:-10px;"/></a><br/>   

        <div id="status" class="alert alert-success"  style="margin-top:20px; width:400px; margin-left:235px; margin-bottom:30px;">

            <h4 class="alert-heading"> Reset your password </h4>

        </div>

        <form class="form-horizontal" name="email_form" id="email_form" method="POST" action="" >

            <fieldset>

                <div class="control-group" style="margin-left:230px">

                    <label class="control-label">Email</label>

                    <div class="controls" align="left">

                        <input name="email" id="email" class="input-large" type="text" placeholder="Enter your Email id"/>

                    </div>

                </div> 

                <div class="control-group">

                    <button type="submit" id="email_send" class="btn btn-inverse submit">GO</button>

                </div>

            </fieldset>

        </form> 

        <form class="form-horizontal" name="code_form" id="code_form" method="POST" action="" >

            <p>Enter the code received in your Email</p>

            <fieldset>

                <div class="control-group" style="margin-left:230px">

                    <label class="control-label">Code</label>

                    <div class="controls" align="left">

                        <input name="code" id="code" class="input-large" type="text" placeholder="#####"/>

                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="control-group">

                    <button type="submit" id="code_send" class="btn btn-inverse  submit">GO</button>

                </div>

            </fieldset>

        </form>                   

        <table style="text-align:left">

            <tr>

                <td width="60%">

                    <form class="form-horizontal" name ="password_form" id="password_form" method ="POST" action ="" >

                        <fieldset>

                            <div class="control-group" style="margin-left:90px;">

                                <label class="control-label">Password</label>

                                <div class="controls">

                                    <input name="password" id="password" class="input-large" type="password" placeholder="Enter your Password" onfocus="Info_Over('#password_on_focus_info')" onblur="Info_Out('#password_on_focus_info')"/>

                                </div>

                            </div>

                            <div class="control-group" style="margin-left:90px;">

                                <label class="control-label">Confirm Password</label>

                                <div class="controls">

                                    <input name="repassword" id="repassword" class="input-large" type="password" placeholder="Re-enter your Password"/>

                                </div>

                            </div>  

                            <div class="control-group" style="margin-left:250px;">

                                <button type="submit" id="password_send" class="btn btn-inverse submit">CONFIRM</button>

                            </div>                          

                        </fieldset>            

                    </form>

                </td>

                <td width="400px" valign="top" style="padding-right:130px">

                    <span id="password_on_focus_info" style="display:none;">

                        Password should be 8 characters or more. Choose a strong password which is a combination of Capital and Small case alphabets, Symbols and Numbers.

                     </span>                                                              

                </td>

            </tr>

        </table>    

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging with Firebug to see what data is being sent back and forth, and what errors might be cropping up?

Comment: My first guess would be that there's an error further up in your JavaScript, so this Ajax call doesn't happen. You need to look at your console to figure out whether there are any errors, whether the ajax call is fired, whether it looks like it should, and what the response is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use an event object for the parameter of the event handler, chrome and safari has a global event object called event when an event is triggered but firefox does not. So `event.preventDefault();` will cause an error.

E.g.

```
$('#email_send').click(function(event) {
```

Comment: +1 Good catch. This would have been caught with Firebug I'm thinking

Comment: @Ulises it would be lost when the form submits.

Comment: mmm interesting,  so the form would submit, despite the error, and still the post won't be processed at the server?

Comment: Never mind, it makes sense. The form submits, however the code fails to cancel the original event and, therefore, post to the server. Causing to refresh the form pretty much

Comment: There should not be a `click` handler on this form in the first place.  Since the OP is using the jQuery Validate plugin, the ajax simply needs to be placed inside the `submitHandler` callback option provided by the plugin.

Comment: After adding $('#email_send').click(function(event), it works now in Firefox 19 and IE 9 :)

Answer (score 1):

As already stated, you are not properly implementing the `preventDefault()` inside of your `click` handler.  However, even if you fix the `preventDefault()` issue, it's likely still not going to work properly.  See:  http://jsfiddle.net/ZEFzx/, where the code inside the `click` handler is not fired at all.

Luckily, you don't need to worry about a `click` handler since the jQuery Validate plugin already has the **submit event handler callback function built in, and this is exactly where you are *supposed* to put your ajax.**

[As per the documentation for the Validate plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions), the `submitHandler` callback function is:

> "Callback for handling the actual submit when the form is valid. Gets
>   the form as the only argument. Replaces the default submit. **The right
>   place to submit a form via Ajax** after it validated."

Try this code instead:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#email_form").validate({
        onkeyup: false,
        rules: {
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            email: {
                required: "Please enter your email ID.",
                email: "Please enter a valid email ID."
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            var email = $('#email').val();
            // var data = $(form).serialize();  // capture all the form data at once
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "reset_code.php",
                data: {
                    email: email
                },
                cache: false,
                success: function (response) {
                    if (response == "Y") {
                        $('#code_form').show();
                        $('#email_send').hide();
                        $('#status').html("Check your mail for the reset code.");
                    } else {
                        $('#status').html("Looks like you have entered a wrong email ID.");
                    }
                }
            });
            return false; // blocks redirect after submission via ajax
        }
    });

});
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/xMg8e/**