# JQuery AJAX Post request doesn't work in IE or FF - Works fine in Chrome

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, firefox

No idea what's going on here. Had some friends test a chat I was working on to find out that it only works in Chrome so far.

The AJAX POST Request doesn't seem to be functioning. In Chrome, I get the success callback. In IE or Firefox get no callbacks period.

You'll see I have the POST shortcut commented out. I was using it but it wasn't working so I switched to ajax for the debugging. I also included the code around it just to make sure it's not the cause also.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#chatWindow").animate({ scrollTop: $("#chatWindow").height()}, 'normal');

    $("#submitForm").submit(function() {
        event.preventDefault();
        var clientMessage = $("#messageText").val();
        //$.post("chatProcess.php", {text: clientMessage});

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "chatProcess.php",
            data: {text: clientMessage},
            dataType: "text",
            error: function(){alert('Error!')},
            success: function(){alert('Success!')}
        });

        $("#messageText").attr("value", "").focus();
        return false;
    });

});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [AJAX call works in Chrome and Safari but not in Firefox and IE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15167417/ajax-call-works-in-chrome-and-safari-but-not-in-firefox-and-ie)

Comment: $("#submitForm").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); ---------- perhaps you can tell use where you got the example so we can fix their code too

Comment: @Musa is right on the money.

Comment: that bit was my limited knowledge trying to write something. Appreciate the help . . . e.preventDefault() fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `event.preventDefault();` or pass the event object as a parameter for your submit function. Since you already have `return false;`, I would just remove `event.preventDefault();`.