# How to call a JavaScript function in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to call a JavaScript function from my jQuery code but won't work.

JavaScript function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showonlyone(thechosenone) {
    var newboxes = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (var x=0; x<newboxes.length; x++) {
        name = newboxes[x].getAttribute("class");
        if (name == 'newboxes') {
            if (newboxes[x].id == thechosenone) {
                newboxes[x].style.display = 'block';
            }
            else {
                newboxes[x].style.display = 'none';
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

jQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $("#img2").on("click", function() { 
        event.preventDefault();
        showonlyone("im2");            
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mean `showonlyone("#im2");`?

Comment: You need to pass `event` into the function in order to use `event.preventDefault()`. @Bram: he doesn't seem to be using jQuery for that portion, so the hash is a possibility, but unlikely.

Comment: similiar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15167417/ajax-call-works-in-chrome-and-safari-but-not-in-firefox-and-ie

Comment: A [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) would be nice

Comment: Bram, that doesn't return a jquery element. $('#im2') does. He gave no mention to what im2 is.

Comment: I don't get any error in my chrome console

Comment: @sksallaj: The `id` of an element.

Comment: Then he spelled it wrong.. he called $("#img2") for his on method. But passes in im2? img2 != im2. If I was him, i'd pass in this.id instead.

Comment: Obligatory comment: jQuery *is* JavaScript. So your question boils down to: "How to call a function?" or "Why is this function not called?"

Comment: $("#img2") is the ID for object that trigger the function is an image  tag with ID=:"img2" an im2 is other ID  data used by showonlyone() java script function .

Comment: Could you please elaborate what the problem is? Is the function really not called (put an `alert` or `console.log` at the beginning)? Or maybe the problem is with the loop? Add some log statements and see how far it goes. Or set breakpoints and inspect the variable values. Just the usual debugging procedure. If you don't know how to do this, it's time [to learn how to **debug** JavaScript](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners).

Comment: @ Felix Kling "Why is this function not called? is more exactly but I am new to jQuery and java script an I need some help for these type of calls.

Comment: Functions are functions. Whether you use jQuery or not, they are always called the same way. Please provide more information about your problem (read the article I linked to), otherwise we are not able to properly help you.

Answer (score 3):

```
event.preventDefault();
```

Probably just js error,

```
$("#img2").on("click", function(event){
 event.preventDefault();
showonlyone("im2");

    });
```

But anyway, it is best to write all code in jquery if you already started.

Comment: You can comment on your own posts

Comment: Can you explain me, why am i getting downvoted and same answer that come 2 min later get 3 upvotes?

Comment: Which answer? Link me to it please

Comment: You need to pass event into the function in order to use event.preventDefault(). @Bram: he doesn't seem to be using jQuery for that portion, so the hash is a possibility, but unlikely. – David Thomas

Comment: Ah, that. Yeah, comments are perfecly fine for partial answers. However, Answers posted as answers should be complete answers. Ideally, they should educate, not just fix some code.

Comment: well i need to get 50 points somehow, to be able to post as commentary.

Comment: You seem to be already there. Welcome and please stay :-)

Comment: "it is best to write all code in jquery if you already started" ... it's good to learn both. However, it's important not to confuse the two. I'm torn about this statement. +1 for pointing out the missing argument, though.

Comment: FWIW, this is only a problem if the OP uses Firefox (because `event` is not global there). Then it would throw an error. But the OP claims that no error is thrown, so this might actually not be the issue (although of course the `event` parameter has to be added).

Comment: @Jan Dvorak well my boss, always teach me to not mix, jquery and javascript, same goes to php frameworks, sql. And besides if you look at his javascript code, you will notice that all this could be written in few lines and it will greatly increase readibility and will not cause confusion. Why write same thing, if its already has been written?

Comment: @user2486415 cloud help me to write the java script function in jQuery because I new to the jQuery ?

Comment: I could, but i fear you wont understand much of it, anyway here is your function i unite them both in 1 $('a.newboxes').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
  $('a.newboxes').not($(this)).hide();
});

Answer (score 2):

It's not that you "*need to pass `event` to the `function`*," as jQuery already does that.

But, you should **name** the argument so you can reference it as `event`:

```
$("#img2").on("click", function(event){
    //                          ^^^^^
    event.preventDefault():
    // etc.
});
```

In JavaScript, `event` isn't a keyword like `this`. Historically, it has [been a global variable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535863.aspx), but isn't standardized as such.

Comment: To clarify: you _can_ reference an argument even if you don't name it: `arguments[0].preventDefault()`.

Comment: @JanDvorak while it's terrible practice to use anonymous arguments, that's nice to know!

Comment: @JanDvorak Sure. But, I've seen backlash given to suggestions of using `arguments`, so thought I'd skip it.

Comment: @Frederik.L did I imply otherwise? :-) However, Mozilla does exactly that (somewhat) for optional arguments: `function(a /*,b*/){if(arguments.length > 1) {b = arguments[1]};...}`

Comment: @JonathanLonowski There are some good uses of `arguments[n]`. Of course, this isn't it :-)