# event.preventDefault(); stopped working in FF

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have the following code, which did work fine until just now, event.preventDefault(); doesn't seem to trigger in FireFox? In Chrome the code still works fine, in Firefox however, it takes me to blank page and I see generated code there instead.

```
    $("#generate_code").click(function(){
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#code').html('Generating Code..');
        hideshow('loading',1);
        setTimeout(function() {
            $.get("generate-code.php", function(data) {
                $("#code").html(data);
            });
            hideshow('loading',0);
        }, 2000);
   });
```

generate-code.php:

```
function generateRandomString($length = 50) {
    $characters = '!@#$%^&*()0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}

$invitecode = generateRandomString();
echo $invitecode;
```

Comment: The PHP code is irrelevant here

Comment: There surely would be someone requesting it, so I just put it up :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [AJAX call works in Chrome and Safari but not in Firefox and IE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15167417/ajax-call-works-in-chrome-and-safari-but-not-in-firefox-and-ie)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be calling `preventDefault` on the event object passed as argument to the handler to make sure that everything works cross-browser.

```
$("#generate_code").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    ...
```

Comment: Same result, Chrome OK, Firefox follows the link

Comment: sorry, using `$("#generate_code").click(function(event)` now, that seems to work

Comment: @MariusProllak Well technically the name of the argument variable doesn't matter. Are you sure that you were ising `e` at both places before?